# Can't load database provider connector drivers

Tags: osgi, eclipselink, equinox

I've installed standalone Equinox and used it as run configuration in eclipse. Project uses EclipseLink as JPA and it's configured to use derby and mysql providers. These providers are packed into bundles and activated in OSGi container. When i run project from eclipse and activate my bundle, the JPA factory is created normally and project works fine.

But! When i run equinox standalone eclipselink can't load database connector driver. Drivers as is wrote are packed as bundles and activated.

I notice, the Eclipse uses the same configuration which i use to run Equinox standalone and the same set of bundles. And the same bundle internal tree the eclipse used to run.

As i understood java classpath isn't needed in OSGi container - there are bundles used. And they are imported in my plugin's manifest.mf.

What's the problem, i can't understand. Why the application cannot find driver classes?

---

Ok, i provide complete exception callstack for derby driver. It seems EL functions normal. For mysql driver the problem is the same, but callstack differs a bit. When i run the same program from eclipse it works right.

That's my configuration:

```
id      State       Bundle
0       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.100.v20120912-141032
                    Fragments=724, 726, 728
694     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.400.v20120828-033
824
695     ACTIVE      com.ibm.icu.base_4.4.2.v20110831
696     ACTIVE      com.mysql.jdbc_5.8.0
697     ACTIVE      javax.el_2.2.0.v201108011116
698     ACTIVE      javax.persistence_2.0.4.v201112161009
699     ACTIVE      javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016
700     ACTIVE      javax.servlet.jsp_2.2.0.v201112011158
702     ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0.v201108120515
703     ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0.v201108120515
704     ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0.v201110170705
705     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.1.v20120521-2329
706     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.200.v20120523-2004
707     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.4.1.v20120521-2329
708     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.4.1.v20120521-2329
709     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_1.4.100.v20120523-1955
710     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.4.401.v20120627-124442
711     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.5.300.v20120622-204750
712     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120521-2346
713     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.100.v20120522-1841
714     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841
715     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841
716     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.0.v20120522-1841
717     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin_2.0.100.v20120606-175127
718     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.equinox_1.0.400.v20120428-0117
719     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.0.v20120522-1841
720     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry_1.1.200.v20120912-125810
721     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.300.v20120912-125810
722     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.5.0.v20120918-182152
723     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.300.v20120731-134527
724     RESOLVED    org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.extensionbundle_1.2.100.v20120522-2049
                    Master=0
725     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator_2.0.0.v20110808-1657
726     RESOLVED    org.eclipse.equinox.transforms.hook_1.0.400.v20120522-2049
                    Master=0
727     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.400.v20120917-191249
728     RESOLVED    org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.v20120524-1707
                    Master=0
729     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.help_3.6.0.v20120521-2344
730     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_8.1.3.v20120522
731     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.http_8.1.3.v20120522
732     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.io_8.1.3.v20120522
733     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522
734     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522
735     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522
736     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.3.v20120522
737     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20120522-1822
738     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.2.300.v20120912-140840
739     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.asm_3.3.1.v201206041142
740     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.core_2.4.0.v20120608-r11652
741     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.jpa_2.4.0.v20120608-r11652
742     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.osgi_2.4.0.v20120608-r11652
743     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.rap.jface_2.0.0.20120821-1934
744     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.rap.jface.databinding_2.0.0.20120821-1934
745     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.rap.rwt_2.0.0.20120821-1934
746     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi_2.0.0.20120821-1934
747     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.rap.ui_2.0.0.20120821-1934
748     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.rap.ui.workbench_1.5.100.20120821-1934
749     ACTIVE      ru.futurelink.testrap_1.0.0.qualifier
750     ACTIVE      org.apache.derby_1.0.0
osgi>
```

That's how i run project:

```
java -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -cp C:/Projects/ru.futurelink.testrap/lib/eclipselink.jar -cp C:/Projects/ru.futurelink.testrap/lib/javax.persistence_1.0.0.jar -cp C:/Projects/ru.futurelink.testrap/lib/derby.jar -cp C:/Projects/ru.futurelink.testrap/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar -jar plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.100.v20120912-141032.jar  -dev file:C:/Equinox/plugins/configuration/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -nl ru_RU -console -consoleLog
```

That's the callstack:

```
[EL Info]: 2012-09-30 20:59:57.778--ServerSession(333070563)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2012-09-30 20:59:58.213--ServerSession(333070563)--java.lang.NullPointerException
2012-09-30 20:59:58.213:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:ERROR:  /examples
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy0.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at ru.futurelink.moneyorganizer.data.MODatabase.<init>(MODatabase.java:13)
    at ru.futurelink.moneyorganizer.ApplicationEntryPoint.createUI(ApplicationEntryPoint.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle.createUI(RWTLifeCycle.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle$UIThreadController.run(RWTLifeCycle.java:289)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.UIThread.run(UIThread.java:102)
Caused by:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.osgi.EMFServiceProxyHandler.invoke(EMFServiceProxyHandler.java:77)
    at $Proxy0.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at ru.futurelink.moneyorganizer.data.MODatabase.<init>(MODatabase.java:13)
    at ru.futurelink.moneyorganizer.ApplicationEntryPoint.createUI(ApplicationEntryPoint.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle.createUI(RWTLifeCycle.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle$UIThreadController.run(RWTLifeCycle.java:289)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.UIThread.run(UIThread.java:102)
Caused by:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:282)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.osgi.EMFServiceProxyHandler.invoke(EMFServiceProxyHandler.java:77)
    at $Proxy0.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at ru.futurelink.moneyorganizer.data.MODatabase.<init>(MODatabase.java:13)
    at ru.futurelink.moneyorganizer.ApplicationEntryPoint.createUI(ApplicationEntryPoint.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle.createUI(RWTLifeCycle.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle$UIThreadController.run(RWTLifeCycle.java:289)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.UIThread.run(UIThread.java:102)
Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.directConnect(DefaultConnector.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:282)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.osgi.EMFServiceProxyHandler.invoke(EMFServiceProxyHandler.java:77)
    at $Proxy0.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at ru.futurelink.moneyorganizer.data.MODatabase.<init>(MODatabase.java:13)
    at ru.futurelink.moneyorganizer.ApplicationEntryPoint.createUI(ApplicationEntryPoint.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle.createUI(RWTLifeCycle.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle$UIThreadController.run(RWTLifeCycle.java:289)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.UIThread.run(UIThread.java:102)
```

And finally the contents of derby.log file:

```
Sun Sep 30 20:59:58 GMT+11:00 2012 Thread[UIThread [1ix4et52sn4jvzywdjyip1m3v],5,main] Class org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/XAConnection, module ignored.
Sun Sep 30 20:59:58 GMT+11:00 2012 Thread[UIThread [1ix4et52sn4jvzywdjyip1m3v],5,main] Class org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver30 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/XAConnection, module ignored.
Sun Sep 30 20:59:58 GMT+11:00 2012 Thread[UIThread [1ix4et52sn4jvzywdjyip1m3v],5,main] Class org.apache.derby.impl.services.jmx.JMXManagementService java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/JMException, module ignored.
Sun Sep 30 20:59:58 GMT+11:00 2012 Thread[UIThread [1ix4et52sn4jvzywdjyip1m3v],5,main] Cleanup action starting
ERROR XBM02: Startup failed due to missing functionality for org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver. Please ensure your classpath includes the correct Derby software.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.missingImplementation(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startServices(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.runWithState(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startMonitor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
```

I use that code to create entity factory:

```
mSystemEntities = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
EntityManager em = mSystemEntities.createEntityManager();
```

And here's my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

<persistence-unit name="prov" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">      
    <class>ru.futurelink.moneyorganizer.data.MOUserEntity</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:/sampledb;create=true" />

      <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>  
</persistence>
```

Comment: Do you have an Import-Package statement in your Manifest for the relevant db packages from the bundle that initializes the db connection?

Comment: There is relevant information missing here. Please show us the exact error and relevant log-messages you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. The Eclipse starts OSGi framework with org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar, but i try to load org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.100.v20120912-141032.jar. I think that framework without launcher doesnt support reflection cause classloader is missing. I'm not shure that the mechanism is of that kind but JPA works now and loads all drivers.

Answer (score 0):

well u havent supplied code and exception so i guess ur doing the following

If ur using JDBC and creating connection by

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, username, password);
```

with sole statement then in osgi generally it throws exception and you wont get any driver and driver is null.

but if u used

```
Class.forName(driver);
```

before creating connection osgi able to load the driver at runtime,

Reflexion in OSGi is bit orthodox.

Comment: EclipseLink uses Class.forName() to create database connection. It's clear from stacktrace i provided in my question. So nothing to do with reflection. )